# Trying to replace the evaluate function. Having an issue with 1 particular case

Tags: coldfusion, evaluate

I am having a heck of a time trying to figure this out. I'm trying to replace this evaluate function.

```
<cfoutput>
 #evaluate('#qry#.#editVal#')#
</cfoutput>
```

But I just can't seem to work it out. Both qry and editVal are in the variables scope and when using evaluate it returns a value for instane the value of

```
#qryVitals.PULSE#
```

I just can't seem to get the notation right to interpret it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: bracket notation, and specifying which scope to look in?

Comment: specifying the scope includes the variables scope.

Answer (score 4):

`#evaluate('#qry#.#editVal#')#` is equivalent to `#VARIABLES[qry][editVal]#`.

As noted by @Leigh, if `VARIABLES[qry]` is of type `query`, you have to specify the row number as well, e.g. `#VARIABLES[qry][editVal][1]#`.

Comment: Do not forget the row number.

Comment: Excellent! thank you so much :) I am not sure why I couldn't figure that one out.

Comment: @StevenPennington: don't forget that if an answer works for you, you can _accept_ it to mark it as done. It is optional but recommended. To do so, click on the tick icon next to the answer you like, so that it turns green.